# Unnecessary Unknown images are appear in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, password-protection, virus

I got the unknown and unnecessary files on wordpress media and there is no option too to delete these files. How can i delete these files help me please !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjTKc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague kindly try to be as specific as you can. Well, You can delete those images from going to upload directory ... its may be there is not title for your images ... make sure those are proper images with proper image details like name, format etc

Comment: are you using Unit Test Data for testing?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now i deleted all the tables of database in server then i import that database, When importing the database there was error and extra more than 14 columns are found in wp_options table with id 0. and in application i can update the post and pages but there is no option add pages,posts and problem with uploading images. There may be the database issue or something else. Would you like to suggest me Please !

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image

1.Tick the checkbox near File

2.Select delete from the Above dropdown(bulk action)

or

you can delete from database:

The Media Library lives in both wp_posts and wp_postmeta.

wp_postmeta contains the image URL
wp_posts contains an entry for each image insertion into a post, along with the post ID. you can get it by query

```
Select * from wp_posts where post_type = 'attachment';
```

Example for delete all media items(Note: Do only if you want to delete all media images)

Locate your WordPress database in phpMyAdmin, then run this SQL command to delete ALL attachments:

```
# First:

 DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN
 (
 SELECT id
 FROM wp_posts
 WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
 );

 # Second:

 DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
```

for reference :[click me](http://snipplr.com/view/70656/)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now i deleted all the tables of database in server then i import that database, When importing the database there was error and extra more than 14 columns are found in wp_options table with id 0. and in application i can update the post and pages but there is no option add pages,posts and problem with uploading images. There may be the database issue or something else. Would you like to suggest me Please !